# Add incrementing value together with other values into a column in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column Processed in a table Employee. Processed value forms a string: "timestamp" + "employeeID" + an incrementing/sequencing value (ie. 1, 2, 3...).

The goal is:

1. The string value would be unique(incrementing value)
2. I can roughly see the time when it was processed(timestamp)
3. Which employee it is about(employeeID)

My current solution has a table made only for the incrementing value part. There is one column, that gets queried for the value, the value is then added to the end of the Processed string. After this, the incrementing table value is updated with the incremented value.
It is created with Oracles sequence and trigger functions: see https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-oracle/

**How ever, I don't think this solutions is optimal and I was wondering if this could be done without the additional table made just for incrementing a single value?**

I am using Oracle Database 19c.

Comment: Why not just have an increasing value for all employees?  Why does it need to be unique per employee?

Comment: So I can query Employees based on the Processed value

Comment: Yeah and why has it to be a single column? Why not just store the data in separate columns?

Comment: if you have the processed value in the same table as the employee, what is the value of having the employee id as part of the processed value. Querying will be more complicated and less performant. It seems you are making things more complicated than they should be. Is it possible to add a processed_date column and a processed_id (which would be that incremented value) ? That gives you maximum fexibility for querying. If you still want to see it in a single column you create and virtual column that concatenates processed_date, processed_id and employee_id

Comment: Is there some reason why you're trying to make this so complex rather than simply having three fields for EMPLOYEE_ID, PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP, and ID_NUMBER (generated using a sequence)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're genuinely concerned about optimisation the only solution is the three column solution. One column for the EMPLOYEE_NO, one for the processed ID and one for the processed timestamp. This provides all the information you need, with the ability to query the table by EMPLOYEE_NO or by date without using a substring function.

It's not clear whether PROCESSED has to be a separate table. Can an employee be processed more than once? Anyway, here is a separate table implementation ...

```
create table processed (
    processed_id number generated always as identity primary key
    , employee_no not null references employees
    , processed_ts timestamp default current_timestamp not null
)
```

... and here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=86e9b3f5dfde739550b31b56dc91ca1e).